# How can I clear form data from another component using material dialog in the same ts file?

Tags: angular

How can I clear form data from another component using material dialog in the same ts file?

Here is my .ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'clear-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './clear-confirmation-dialog.html'
})
export class ClearConfimationDialog {

  clearForm(){
    /** FUNCTION TO CLEAR FORM DATA **/
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-enter-user',
  templateUrl: './enter-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enter-user.component.scss']
})
export class EnterUserComponent implements OnInit {

/** THIS IS THE FORM DATA **/
user = {
  name: '',
  address: ''
}

}
```

Comment: Share the `html` where you call this selector `clear-confirmation-dialog` and share the html for `EnterUserComponent`

Comment: I just want to call `clearForm()` from `ClearConfimationDialog` to clear `user` array in `EnterUserComponent`

Comment: Does these components have parent child relationships ?

Comment: These 2 components are in the same ts file.

Comment: Might solve your problem just use inheritance on your  `ClearConfimationDialog` which reads as `export class ClearConfimationDialog extends EnterUserComponent ` so you might get the user data - reset it inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the  `EnterUserComponent` to the `ClearConfimationDialog`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'clear-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './clear-confirmation-dialog.html'
})
export class ClearConfimationDialog {

  enter_user_component:EnterUserComponent;

  clearForm(){
    /** FUNCTION TO CLEAR FORM DATA **/
   this.enter_user_component.clearForm()
  }

 constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => EnterUserComponent)) enter_user_component:EnterUserComponent){
        this.enter_user_component = enter_user_component
  }

}
```

By the way, only when the `app-enter-user` include the `clear-confirmation-dialog` will work

for example:

```
 enter-user.component.html:

....
<clear-confirmation-dialog></clear-confirmation-dialog>
....
```

You better add `@Optional()` & `@Host()` decorator to **enter_user_component**

> More about forwardRef:
>
> https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef

Comment: I've tried injecting `EnterUserComponent` then I got this error
`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ClearConfimationDialog`

Comment: These 2 components are in the same `.ts` file

Comment: i have updated the answer ,you can use forwardRef to avoid this problem

Comment: Looks like your first answer was correct, I just placed the dialog component after the EnterUserComponent and it works

Comment: forwardRef solve the problem that  allow to refer to references which are not yet defined.  you  can also change the placement of two components  in same file :)

Comment: I haven't tried yet but I think that might be a good solution as well. Thanks :)